# Creating deep object with value via loop

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create a deep object equivalent to `user['address']['street'] = VALUE`

If I have a string like:

```
var user = 'user[address][street]' 
user.split(/[[\]]{1,2}/).slice(0,-1);    // which gives me [user, address, street]
```

I'm trying to get:

```
user: {
    address: {
        street : VALUE
    }
}
```

I've managed to figure out how to create the deep object:

```
var newObj = obj
split.forEach(function(item){
    newObj = newObj[item] = {}
})
```

but I'm struggling with setting the value on the last property.

http://jsfiddle.net/catc/8LfLk5a5/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8LfLk5a5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a check to see if you're at the last item in the list and then assign the value.

```
var newObj = obj
var last = split.length - 1;
split.forEach(function(item, idx){
    newObj = newObj[item] = (idx == last) ? value : {};
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/THEtheChad/qfn9ny4n/

## Edit

You might also consider turning this into a function so you can easily reuse it.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/THEtheChad/owvu7t7h/